# How to modify my T-SQL query so that it outputs all records which appear twice or more based on 2 different periods?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have the following T-SQL query:

```
Use MyDatabase

;WITH Query_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        ResID, Name,
        ArrivalDate, Status,
        ProfileID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ResID] ORDER BY [StayDate]) AS xy      
    FROM
        (SELECT * 
         FROM View1) xx
)
SELECT * 
FROM Query_CTE
WHERE Query_CTE.[xy] = 1
```

I need to modify the above query so that it outputs all the records whose `ArrivalDate` is between `'2018-04-01'`and `'2018-12-31'` which are **also** present in the list of records having their `ArrivalDate` less than `'2018-04-01'` based on `ProfileID`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to a where clause to your CTE, to get only the records where arrival date is between `2018-04-01` and `2018-12-31`.
Then you need to add `EXISTS` to check if the same profile id also exists in records before `2018-04-01`:

```
;WITH Query_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
         ResID
        ,Name
        ,ArrivalDate
        ,Status
        ,ProfileID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ResID] ORDER BY [StayDate]) AS xy      

    FROM View1 v1
    WHERE ArrivalDate >= '2018-04-01'
    AND  ArrivalDate <= '2018-12-31'
    AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM View1 v2
        WHERE v2.ProfileID = v1.ProfileID
        AND v2.ArrivalDate < '2018-04-01'
    )
)

SELECT * FROM Query_CTE

WHERE Query_CTE.[xy] = 1
```

Side note: The derived table in the cte is completely redundant, so I've removed it.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try but it seems a closing bracket is missing somewhere.